# Insert emoji with zero width joiner using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have not been able to successfully insert an emoji into the DOM using Javascript when I am given the codepoints and zero width joiners are used.

Consider this emoji: ‍‍

I am able to create a string that looks like this:
`&zwj;&zwj;`

and insert it into the innerHtml of an element but the 3 characters end up getting displayed instead of the single combined character. If you look at the html on this page for this character, you can see that the html is formatted in the same way as my string is:

https://emojipedia.org/family-woman-woman-boy/

This is only an issue when zero width joiners are used.

So doing this:

`el.innerHTML = "&zwj;&zwj;"`

should result in a single character but it doesn't, so how can I get the single character to display. NOTE: the character cannot just be added by typing the text into an editor. The content is generated by javascript.

Comment: Sorry, what is the question here.  How are you trying to insert the above, could we see some code?

Comment: @Keith I updated my post with a line of code.

Comment: Your line of code seems to work for me..  What browser you using?

Comment: Latest version of Chrome.

Comment: So running the snippet I have posted here, does not work either?..  I'm Chrome on Windows 10 -> Version 68.0.3440.106

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what the question is here, but if you have a good UTF8/Unicode editor you can of course just paste the emoji into your text file.

If this is problematic you could build it up using HTML escaping.

Below I have done both, the first just pasting into the editor, unfortunately SO editor is not the best here.  And the second one I use using HTML escaping..

Hope this helps..

> update:  Using your version also seems to work for me using Chrome,
>   what browsers are you using..?

```js
document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML = "‍‍";
document.querySelector("#container2").innerHTML =
  "&#x1F469;&zwj;&#x1F469;&zwj;&#x1F466;";
document.querySelector("#container3").innerHTML =
  "&zwj;&zwj;";
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
<div id="container2">
</div>
<div id="container3">
</div>
```

Comment: The second line of your code is what was wrong in mine. I need to use &#x. Thanks!